# Nullpointer exception when trying to receive UDP multicast

Tags: java, udp, multicast, vert.x

i'm puzzeled after a few attempts to get a simple UDP multicast receiver working.
After my own code did not work as expected i tried out the exact example posted in the vertx documentation:

```
DatagramSocket socket = vertx.createDatagramSocket(new DatagramSocketOptions());
socket.listen(1234, "0.0.0.0", asyncResult -> {
  if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
    socket.handler(packet -> {
      // Do something with the packet
    });

    // join the multicast group
    socket.listenMulticastGroup("230.0.0.1", asyncResult2 -> {
        System.out.println("Listen succeeded? " + asyncResult2.succeeded());
    });
  } else {
    System.out.println("Listen failed" + asyncResult.cause());
  }
});
```

After executing, i got the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: networkInterface
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel.joinGroup(NioDatagramChannel.java:409)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel.joinGroup(NioDatagramChannel.java:368)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel.joinGroup(NioDatagramChannel.java:362)
    at io.vertx.core.datagram.impl.DatagramSocketImpl.listenMulticastGroup(DatagramSocketImpl.java:90)
```

I can get it to work when providing the right IP address of the network interface (e.g. 192.168.178.52) instead of 0.0.0.0. However, this means iterating over all network interfaces and adding a socket per interface.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Something goes wrong during initialization, you'll need to carefully debug it. Probably `NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(localAddress().getAddress())` is the problem

Answer (score 1):

UDP multicast listening is incredibly error prone, especially in virtual machines.

This is from my production code. First, to get a valid interface:

```
static NetworkInterface mainInterface() throws SocketException {
    final ArrayList<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
    final NetworkInterface networkInterface = interfaces.stream().filter(ni -> {
        boolean isLoopback = false;
        boolean supportsMulticast = false;
        boolean isVirtualbox = false;
        try {
            isLoopback = ni.isLoopback();
            supportsMulticast = ni.supportsMulticast();
            isVirtualbox = ni.getDisplayName().contains("VirtualBox") || ni.getDisplayName().contains("Host-Only");
        } catch (IOException loopbackTestFailure) {
        }
        final boolean hasIPv4 = ni.getInterfaceAddresses().stream().anyMatch(ia -> ia.getAddress() instanceof Inet4Address);
        return supportsMulticast && !isLoopback && !ni.isVirtual() && hasIPv4 && !isVirtualbox;
    }).sorted(Comparator.comparing(NetworkInterface::getName)).findFirst().orElse(null);
    return networkInterface;
}
```

Then, the most bullet-proof datagram socket creation:

```
String multicastAddress = "230.0.0.1";
NetworkInterface networkInterface = mainInterface();
Future isListening = Future.future();
vertx.createDatagramSocket(new DatagramSocketOptions()
            .setReuseAddress(true)
            .setReusePort(true))
            .listen(6112, "0.0.0.0", next -> {
                next.result().listenMulticastGroup(multicastAddress, networkInterface.getName(), null, listener -> {
                    final DatagramSocket socket = listener.result();
                    socket.handler(packet -> {
                        // Your handler here
                    });

                    isListening.complete();
                });
            });
```

Observe my choice of a higher-than-1024 port, the reuse flags, and the special casing for VirtualBox.

Comment: Nice, thanks! This is very similar to the solution I ended up with. There's simply no alternative to iterating over network interfaces and sorting the ones out that just won't work.

Comment: @DoctorPangloss Have you had any luck trying to use another address besides 0.0.0.0 for binding to the datagram socket when calling listen()? So far multicast only works for me using 0.0.0.0, any other address I can only receive unicast UDP, but not multicast.