# Does UDP multicast works with an address other than 0.0.0.0 in VertX 3

Tags: vert.x

### Problem 1: It only works when using the 0.0.0.0 address

I'm trying to receive and send multicast messages using Vertx 3.9.2.
I first tried to follow the [example](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_multicast) in the project's documentation but encountered the [NullPointerException problem described in this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449129/nullpointer-exception-when-trying-to-receive-udp-multicast). However, I was able to receive multicast messages after specifying a network interface when joining the multicast group.

```
socket.listen(5001, "0.0.0.0", handler1 -> {
    if (handler1.succeeded()) {
        socket.listenMulticastGroup("234.3.2.1", "en0", null, handler2 -> {
            LOG.debug("Joined multicast group? {}", handler2.succeeded());
            socket.handler(packet -> LOG.debug("Received packet: {}", packet));
        });
    } else {
        LOG.error("Failure to listen on address", handler1.cause());
    }
});
```

Nonetheless, receiving multicast messages only works when using the `0.0.0.0` address. I never get multicast messages if I use the address of any of my network interfaces. I first tried like:

```
socket.listen(5001, "192.168.1.10", handler1 -> {
    if (handler1.succeeded()) {
        socket.listenMulticastGroup("234.3.2.1", "en0", null, handler2 -> {
            LOG.debug("Joined multicast group? {}", handler2.succeeded());
            socket.handler(packet -> LOG.debug("Received packet: {}", packet));
        });
    } else {
        LOG.error("Failure to listen on address", handler1.cause());
    }
});
```

And also this other version:

```
socket.listen(5001, "192.168.1.10", handler1 -> {
    if (handler1.succeeded()) {
        socket.listenMulticastGroup("234.3.2.1", handler2 -> {
            LOG.debug("Joined multicast group? {}", handler2.succeeded());
            socket.handler(packet -> LOG.debug("Received packet: {}", packet));
        });
    } else {
        LOG.error("Failure to listen on address", handler1.cause());
    }
});
```

In all three cases the multicast group is successfully joined. But no multicast messages are received with the last two.

### Problem 2: Disabling the Loopback mode seems to not work

I'm using the same socket to read and write multicast. When I'm able to receive multicast messages (by binding to 0.0.0.0), I've notice that all the messages written are also received back by the read operation.

This is how the socket is created:

```
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
DatagramSocket socket = vertx.createDatagramSocket(
    new DatagramSocketOptions()
        .setReuseAddress(true)
        .setReusePort(true)
        .setLoopbackModeDisabled(true)
        .setIpV6(false));
```

One interesting observation is that when binding to another address (like the examples above) I'm able to write multicast messages out and the messages are not "heard back". But I've wonder if the reason is that multicast messages are not received to begin with.

### It seems to be a known issue of sorts

I did find an [open issue in GitHub](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/issues/2206) that seems to be related to the same problem. It points to a link that's currently broken, but no final resolution is provided.

I truly hope someone can shed some light on the matter.

### Update 1

The problem happens in Mac OS X Catalina 10.15.5 and Alpine Linux 3.12 in Docker.

### Update 2

Receiving multicast messages also work if you use the multicast address on the `listen` call.

```
socket.listen(5001, "234.3.2.1", handler1 -> {
    if (handler1.succeeded()) {
        socket.listenMulticastGroup("234.3.2.1", "en0", null, handler2 -> {
            LOG.debug("Joined multicast group? {}", handler2.succeeded());
            socket.handler(packet -> LOG.debug("Received packet: {}", packet));
        });
    } else {
        LOG.error("Failure to listen on address", handler1.cause());
    }
});
```

One cannot write using the socket when calling `listen` like that however.

Comment: Vert.x uses Netty which in turn uses `java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel`. 
I ended up using `java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel` directly and the only way I've been able to use the same channel
for reading/writing is by binding to 0.0.0.0.

Disabling loopback works when using `java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel` directly. From a quick look at the code 
it seems like Vert.x is using the native transports (KQUEUE, EPOLL) when running on MacOS and Linux. It seems
that it only disables the loopback when using the JDK transport.